# Show that the perturbation of identity satisfies certain continuity and Lipschitz properties

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, optimization, determinant, numerical-optimization

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $u\in C^{0,\:1}(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d)$ and $c:=|u|_{C^{0,\:1}(\mathbb R^d,\:\mathbb R^d)}$ (the semi-norm given by the Lipschitz constant).

I would like to show that there is a $\tau>0$ such that $$T_t(x):=x+tu(x)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R^d$$

satisfies

1. $T_t$ is a bijection for all $t\in[0,\tau]$;
2. $T,T^{-1}\in C^{0,\:1}(\mathbb R^d,C^0([0,\tau],\mathbb R^d))$.

It's easy to see that $$\left\|T(x)-T(y)\right\|_{C^0([0,\:\tau],\:\mathbb R^d)}\le(1+\tau c)\left\|x-y\right\|\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y\in\mathbb R^d.$$ Assuming $\tau\le(2c)^{-1}$ (**I've read at other places that we need to assume $\tau\le\min(1,(2c)^{-1})$ but I don't understand why**), we can show that $T_t$ is bijective for all $t\in[0,\tau]$:

In fact, let $t\in[0,\tau]$, $y\in\mathbb R^d$ and $$f(x):=y-(T_t(x)-x)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R^d.$$ Then \begin{equation}\begin{split}\left\|f(x_1)-f(x_2)\right\|&=\left\|(x_1-x_2)-(T_t(x_1)-T_t(x_2))\right\|\\&\le tc\left\|x_1-x_2\right\|\end{split}\tag2\end{equation} for all $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb R^d.$ If $\tau\le(2c)^{-1}$, then $tc\le2^{-1}<1$ and hence $f$ is a strict contraction so that, by the Banach fixed-point theorem, there is a unique $x\in\mathbb R^d$ with $f(x)=x$, which is equivalent to $y=T_t(x)$.

From the reverse triangle inequality and $(2)$ we see that $$\left\|x_1-x_2\right\|\le2\left\|T_t(x_1)-T_t(x_2)\right\|\tag3$$ for all $t\in[0,\tau]$ and $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb R^d$ and hence $$\left\|T_t^{-1}(x)-T_t^{-1}(y)\right\|\le2\left\|T_t(T_t^{-1}(x))-T_t(T_t^{-1}(y))\right\|=2\left\|x-y\right\|\tag4$$ for all $t\in[0,\tau]$ and $x,y\in\mathbb R^d$.

> How can we show the remaining claims? And, if $u\in C^1(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d)$, under which condition can we show that ${\rm D}T_t=\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb R^d}+t{\rm D}u$ has a nonnegative determinant?

Comment: What does $C^{0,\:1}(\mathbb R^d,C^0([0,\tau],\mathbb R^d)$ mean?

Comment: @zhw. Is is the space of Lipschitz continuous functions from $\mathbb R^d$ to $C^0([0,\tau],\mathbb R^d)$, where the latter is the space of continuous functions from $[0,\tau],\mathbb R^d)$. I'm slightly abusing notation when I write that $T$ belongs to this space; what's meant is that the map $x\mapsto t\mapsto T_t(x)$ is in this space.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this idea/notation at all.

Comment: @zhw. I'm sure you understand it. Look, $T$ is a function depending on two arguments, $t$ and $x$. So, the natural way to think about $T$ is as a function from $[0,\tau]\times\mathbb R^d$ to $\mathbb R^d$. However, we may likewise think about $T$ as a function mapping $t\in[0,\tau]$ to a function $T_t$ from $\mathbb R^d$ to $\mathbb R^d$. In the same way, we may think about $T$ as a function mapping $x\in\mathbb R^d$ to a function $T(x)$ from $[0,\tau]$ to $\mathbb R^d$. And in this last interpretation, the claim $T\in C^{0,\:1}(\mathbb R^d,C^0([0,\tau],\mathbb R^d)$ has to be understood.

Comment: You were missing a parenthesis I think. The notation should be $C^{0,\:1}(\mathbb R^d,C^0([0,\tau],\mathbb R^d)\,).$ Right?

Comment: @zhw. Yes, of course. Fixed that.

Comment: So it looked to me like the thing had the form $C^{0,1}(X,Y,Z),$ which made no sense to me.

Comment: Assuming in addition $u\in C^1,$ it looks to me like there exists $\tau>0$ such that $DT_t$ has positive determinant everywhere. Is this of interest?

Comment: @zhw. Yeah, I think I didn't noticed that when I wrote the question, but if $(T_t)_t$ is *any* family of $C^1$-diffeomorphisms on an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb R^d$ such that $T_0=\operatorname{id}_U$ and $[0,\tau)\times U\ni(t,x)\mapsto{\rm D}T_t(x)$ is continuous in the first argument uniformly with respect to the second, then there is a $\delta\in(0,\tau]$ such that $\det{\rm D}T_t(x)>0$ for all $(t,x)\in[0,\delta)\times U$. So, this would follow if we can show the continuity claim.

Comment: That doesn't work, because you can have uniform continuity with first derivatives blowing up. For example, take $d=1$ and

$$u(x)= \frac{\sin(x^4)}{1+x^2}.$$

Then $u$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R.$ For $t\ge 0,$ set $T_t=I +tu.$  Then $T_t(x)$ is uniformly continuous in each variable. No matter how small $t>0$ is, $D(I+tu)(x)$ will take on negative values somewhere.

Comment: However, in this problem $u$ is Lipschitz and $C^1,$ so all first derivatives are bounded. So things will work out if $t$ is small enough.

Comment: @zhw. I'm not sure if I can follow. $T_0=\operatorname{id}_U$ and hence $\det{\rm D}T_0(x)=1>0$ for all $x\in U$. Now, $\det:\mathfrak L(\mathbb R^d)\to\mathbb R$ is continuous. So, if $[0,\tau)\times U\ni(t,x)\mapsto{\rm D}T_t()$ is continuous in the first argument uniformly with respect to the second, we can find $\delta>0$ with $\det{\rm D}T_t(x)>0$ for all $(t,x)\in[0,\delta)\times U$. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, I misread what you wrote. Instead of $DT,$ I read it as $T.$ Dumb. So cancel the above two comments. I now bow out of this one.